# my emr cluster is being terminated with error after the status is being set to starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster, amazon-emr

Hi when I create EMR cluster. The status says it is being created but after 58 minutes it throws in error saying `Master - 1: Error provisioning instances`. [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U2Y3.png)(Screenshot of error attached) I tried multiple times but all attempts was failed.

I was following the AWS documentation on how to create EMR cluster

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-gs.html
```

[Create EMR cluster on AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og0qm.png)(Picture from the documentation attached)

where did i go wrong? I want to successfully create EMR cluster and attach Jupiter notebook to the cluster. Is there a documentation to successfully create a cluster and make the cluster to run without being terminated after 58 Minutes

Please suggest me what has to be done.

Thankyou.

Comment: We need more details of the problem to help. Can you dig around and find more information / details / error messages? I'd also check things like IAM policy, service control policies, service limits. Try provisioning the same instance size in the same AZ to see if that works.

Comment: @Tim, I am unable to launch cluster. there are no IAM policy as i am the root user. The instance automatically terminates with an error message "Terminated with errorsFailed to start the job flow due to an internal error". I tried all permutations and combination not sure what is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rgzv posted a "link only" answer that posted to an [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=119332&tstart=0#annotation-21311), which requires a login to access, so the answer was deleted by a moderator.

The answer linked to appears to say that the subnet that hosts the EMR cluster needs a route table entry 0.0.0.0/0 to the internet gateway. That suggests that the EMR cluster needs access to public resources or AWS endpoints.

Sometimes VPC endpoints can be used instead of an internet gateway.